# How to Implement the openURL in react-native-community Google Signin for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

Following the [GoogleSignin docs openURL part](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/blob/master/docs/ios-guide.md), the block of code is inserted in the `AppDelegate.m` file.
[image]
[image]

Resulted to this issue.

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/client-fjhdzotydjguqzewjniwgbnbrzdo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/client.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/client.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Desktop/theapp/client/ios/client/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Is it necessary to insert the above block of openURL code if I have multiple OAuth providers Facebook, Google in the Login Flow?

[image]

Or does the latest version automatically configure the openURL for multiple listeners?